# Why MANIFEST file is showing 'No available bundle exports package'?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, manifest, osgi-bundle

My MANIFEST file is not able to see the following three projects:

```
Import-Package: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation;version=
 "2.5",javax.xml.bind.annotation,org.springframework.http,org.springfram
 ework.web.client.
```

I have these projects in my POM still MANIFEST is not able to figure out. I tried to add one of these by adding it to a lib folder and then adding it to my build path to see if it will remove the error for that in the MANIFEST but still no luck. Where is the MANIFEST file looking for these packages?

NOTE: This is a Java project but I wanted to consume this in a plugin project so I converted it into a plugin project.

[image]

[image: Added one to my build path still no luck.]

Comment: did you update your project after changing your dependencies in POM.xml